# how pci_get_device function works, Is it requires register address MMIO where the device exists Can it be used for DMA

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, dynamic-memory-allocation, pci

For example, I have a pci driver and its registered in __init I need to know can I use in any other function inside driver c file like

```
   struct pci_dev dev= pci_get_device(INTEL_VENDOR_HEX_VAL, INTEL_E1000E_DEVICE_HEX, NULL);

   //I got values of INTEL_VENDOR_HEX_VAL and INTEL_E1000E_DEVICE_HEX from E1000e device datasheet
```

Then Can I do DMA like this

```
        struct pci_dev dev= pci_get_device(INTEL_VENDOR_HEX_VAL, INTEL_E1000E_DEVICE_HEX, NULL);
        pci_enable_device(dev);
        pci_set_master(dev);
        struct my_intel_RX_descriptor rx_desc = dma_alloc_coherent(&dev->dev, INTEL_RX_RING_BYTES,
                     &RxPhyAddr, GFP_KERNEL);
        struct page *data; //Consider data is global
        int node = dev_to_node(dev.dev);
dma_addr_t mapping;
        data = alloc_pages_node(node, GFP_KERNEL, get_order(RX_BUF_SIZE));
        dma_addr_t mapping = dma_map_page(d, data, 0, RX_BUF_SIZE, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);
```

And elsewhere I do this

```
        void *rx_buf=page_address(data);
        rx_buf= ether_plus_ip_tcp_hdr_obj;
```

In above line will it write to NIC card? since I am Mapped PCI_dev to kernel Page. If not then how to make it work any corrections

Or

```
     pci_read_config_word(dev, PCI_VENDOR_ID, &id);
```

in some char driver or block driver

Comment: You want to access a device owned by a different driver? Not recommended.

Comment: @stark No I want to access device in the same driver I registered the pci_dev. how to do it correctly, how do u say is `get_pci_device` to access device in different driver. I dont think so, please clarify

Comment: @stark My device owned by same driver c file, but yes I created char driver as well in the same driver c file, so I want to own it in my own driver just different part of driver, `char` part of device driver (the other part is pci dev), how to get pci_dev object in char dev function (read function) of same c file and do coherent dma mapping thats the question, OR `what if I keep my pci_dev object as global will it work then, then in that case I already have the pci device in char device read function` please let me know thanks just tell me will it work

Comment: If you are registering a PCI driver, you should not need to call `pci_get_device` at all. The `struct pci_dev *` will be passed to your PCI driver's `probe` handler.

Comment: If its your device, why do you need to find it?

Comment: @stark basically technically its not my same pci device functionality.But really its my driver in same c file. Is it possible?You know I just cant keep pci_dev as global because it will be bit strange.But this way I can access the pci_dev using `pci_get_device` in some other function linked to some other driver means my single driver c file is basically servicing as char driver plus pci driver.Because in school assignment at university,teacher said he does't want any syscall or anything. it was a class assignment. this way I can access the nic card and read and write packets to it in DMA area.

Comment: @stark and also learn about how drivers work

Comment: If you want to learn how drivers work then do it the right way.  Separate the two drivers and design a proper API not based on global variables or searching for devices.  Proper calls to a driver get passed a handle to the device struct.  For e1000 a handle to the netdev is stored in the pci_dev.

Comment: @stark `... For e1000 a handle to the netdev is stored in the pci_dev` Do u mean register netdev and pci driver as normal. So I like to do in `__init`,  `pci_register_driver(&my_pci_driver);` and in probe of pci driver do `my_struct_obj = netdev_priv(struct_net_device_obj);` and `my_struct_ob->dev=net_device_object;` and `my_struct_obj->pci_dev=pci_dev_object` pci_dev_object which I received as probe function argument. Then will it work? Is this what u are saying. It make sense though. Please confirm, Its bit different but does it sounds right?

Comment: Or how to extract a handle to `net_device` from pci_dev. Please also explain this and let me know the above comment way is it possible.

Comment: Better than me explaining: https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/

Comment: I heard that there is also forth edition. Wonder where one can find one of that

Comment: There is no forth edition, it got postponed.

Comment: @0andriy any other resource which I can use as reference for network drivers?